# Build failed unable to resolve class com.android.build.output file react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I am running my application on Android with React-Native and its appear the next error :

"build file 'C:\Users........\android\app\build.gradle': 3: unable to resolve class com.android.build.OutputFile"

I ve tried with Android Studio and GenyMotion but the problem is the same.

Anybody has an idea of what happen ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 13):

I got a similar error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/mick/Codes/git/projects/alerto-balita/AlertoBalitaApp/android/app/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/mick/Codes/git/projects/alerto-balita/AlertoBalitaApp/android/app/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/Users/mick/Codes/git/projects/alerto-balita/AlertoBalitaApp/android/app/build.gradle': 3: unable to resolve class com.android.build.OutputFile
   @ line 3, column 1.
     import com.android.build.OutputFile
     ^

  1 error
```

In my case I accidentally removed `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` in the project `build.gradle` returning it solved the compilation problem

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error :(

but I resolved by

Just **remove** the **gradle plugin** from vs code and **restart the vs code**.

Comment: I also disabled Gradle for Java of Microsoft from vscode extension. no problem. but is it good to go?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in the section:

> buildscript { dependencies { ... } }

From file:

> android / build.gradle

Has the line:

> classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")